# How to get > 240 days data from today's date in SQL Server, where particular unit key of some records are within and outside 240 days

Tags: sql-server

How to get > 240 days (or 8 month) data from today's date in SQL Server, where particular unit_key of some records are within and outside 240 days.So eliminate those records.Data available in this table from 2019 and searching records start from 01.01.2020 (allocation_date)

FL_DATA TABLE

| fl_key | fl_no | allocation_date | unit_key | unit_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FL/3352 | 02/20/2021 | 54 | A Pradhan |
| 5 | FL/3374 | 07/14/2020 | 54 | A Pradhan |
| 8 | FL/3469 | 08/16/2019 | 54 | A Pradhan |
| 11 | FL/3578 | 06/22/2019 | 54 | A Pradhan |
| 15 | FL/3670 | 06/15/2020 | 60 | D Raj |
| 22 | FL/3692 | 04/22/2020 | 60 | D Raj |
| 9 | FL/3542 | 07/20/2020 | 64 | K Parihar |
| 33 | FL/3599 | 05/27/2020 | 64 | K Parihar |
| 46 | FL/3645 | 11/13/2019 | 64 | K Parihar |
| 48 | FL/3640 | 02/22/2021 | 22 | R Raja |
| 52 | FL/3724 | 12/28/2020 | 22 | R Raja |
| 12 | FL/3342 | 03/20/2020 | 22 | R Raja |
| 13 | FL/3355 | 12/20/2019 | 22 | R Raja |

Output Table:

| fl_no | unit_key | unit_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FL/3670 | 60 | D Raj |
| FL/3692 | 60 | D Raj |
| FL/3542 | 64 | K Parihar |
| FL/3599 | 64 | K Parihar |

My probable query is

SELECT fl_no,unit_key,unit_name
from FL_DATA
where DATEDIFF(day, allocation_date, getdate()) > 240
and allocation_date>='01/01/2020'
order by unit_key

But in where clause if I write >240 or <240, in that case data is showing only within or without the DAY boundary mentioned in the query. But here I am talking about some unit_key belongs within 240 and outside 240 days, that data should be eliminated by the query because I want only those unit_key who have not registered with us for more than 240 days. Rest others unit_key should be in query output.

In my table, data is available from the year 2018 and my requirement of data is from year 2020 to till date that’s why I have mentioned "allocation_date>='01/01/2020'”

I hope I got my point through to you and expecting the exact query format.

Comment: Have you considered `DATEADD`? What *have* you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Explain the logic that takes a table of a dozen or so rows and condenses that down to a resultset of 4 rows.  The phrase "searching records start from 01.01.2020" seems to be a filter to be included in some WHERE clause. Make an effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
SELECT  T.fl_no,
        T.unit_key,
        T.unit_name,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, T.allocation_date, GETDATE()) AS days_past
FROM    FL_DATA     AS T

WHERE   T.allocation_date >= '2020-01-01'
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    FL_DATA     AS  Recent
            
            WHERE   Recent.allocation_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -240, GETDATE())
            AND     Recent.unit_key = T.unit_key
        )
```

Please let me know if it solves it, or if some adjustments are needed

Comment: This query is absolutely working fine. Could you please display total no. of days in separate column

Comment: I added a new answer for this request, let me know if it matches your expectations

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to include the days in separate column, I suggest using OUTER APPLY instead:

```
SELECT  T.fl_no,
        T.unit_key,
        T.unit_name,
        unit_key_agg.days_past
FROM    FL_DATA                 AS T

OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  DATEDIFF(
                DAY,
                MAX(Recent.allocation_date),
                GETDATE()
            )                   AS  days_past
    FROM    FL_DATA             AS  Recent
        
    WHERE   Recent.unit_key     =   T.unit_key
)   AS      unit_key_agg

WHERE   T.allocation_date       >=  '2020-01-01'
AND     unit_key_agg.days_past  >   240
```

This query would give you this result:

| fl_no | unit_key | unit_name | days_past |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FL/3670 | 60 | D Raj | 375 |
| FL/3692 | 60 | D Raj | 375 |
| FL/3542 | 64 | K Parihar | 340 |
| FL/3599 | 64 | K Parihar | 340 |

Comment: This query is working fine. But I need each row days_past value, not MAX value for a particular unit_key.

Comment: I see, so I guess the first answer was a better option. I edited the first answer - added past_days column. If it's ok, please mark the answer as the right answer, thanks :)

Comment: First answer met my expectations and is working fine.